# How to correctly configure a route issue in ASP.Net WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

After developing a simple test ASP.Net WebApi solution to implement Unity interface DI into my Controller I have hit an issue with getting my API to route to the relevant methods correctly.

Typing in the following URL will return the first GET method as expected:

```
http://localhost:1035/api/values
```

Typing in a parameter to hit the GetSelectedPerson method in the controller is never registered:

```
http://localhost:1035/api/values/Test
```

Hopefully someone can tell me where I'm going wrong, heres the relevant code.

RouteConfig from the App_Start folder:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Here is the WebApi config again from the App_Start folder:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new
            {
                id = RouteParameter.Optional
            }
        );

        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
    }
}
```

Here are the two GET HTTP methods I've implemented within the 'Values' controller:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{

    private IPersonCreator _createPerson;

    public ValuesController(IPersonCreator createPerson)
    {
        _createPerson = createPerson;
    }

    //GET api/values
    public IPerson Get()
    {
        return _createPerson.CreateNewPerson();
    }

    //**********Issue: This Method is never hit.**********
    public IPerson GetSelectedPerson(string nameOfPerson)
    {
        IPerson selectedPerson = null;

        var returnedPeople = _createPerson.CreateNewPeople();

        foreach (var person in returnedPeople)
        {
            if (person.Name == "John")
            {
                selectedPerson = person;
            }
        }

        return selectedPerson;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a parameter binding problem. In the default route the expected parameter name is `id`, however, in your action you have `nameOfPerson`.

You have two options here, you can either rename your `nameOfPerson` parameter to be `id` i.e.

```
public IPerson GetSelectedPerson(string id)
```

or alternatively add a *specific* route which expects a `nameOfPerson` parameter i.e.

```
// place after default route
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "PersonByNameApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{nameOfPerson}",
    defaults: new
    {
        nameOfPerson = RouteParameter.Optional
    }
);
```